# Using reel js object animated by a slider (jquery ui) inside a book of moodle. It doesn't work

Tags: 3d, slider, moodle

I am trying to make a reel js object being controle by slider (jquery ui) inside a book of the moodle lms.

When I teste it outside moodle it works fine. But when I upload it as a chapter of a book on moodle it doesn't work at all. The object can be rotated manually (dragging the object) but doesn't work with the slider.

Thanks in advance.

I am using moodle 3.5 , reel js version 1.3.0 and jquery 1.11.1 and jquery.ui 1.10.3

html

```
<div class="ResponsiveProductRight gallery-container col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                        <div class="rg-image-container">
                        <div class="rg-image selected">
                            <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                                <img src="img/un01_a01_p01_1.jpg"
                                      class="selected"
                                      id="animCoracao"
                                      data-cw="true"
                                      data-frame="1"
                                      data-speed="0"
                                      data-duration="1"
                                      data-velocity="0"
                                      data-brake="0"
                                      data-draggable="false"
                                      data-cursor="default"
                                      data-indicator="-1"
                                      data-preloader="0"
                                      >
                            </div>
                            <div style="display:block;" class="rg-slider-container">
                                <div class="rg-slider-outer">
                                    <!--
                                    <div class="rg-slider-btn pull-left"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></div>
                                    -->
                                    <div class="rg-slider-wrap scroll-bar-wrap ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom pull-left" style="background: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                        <div class="rg-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

Javascript

$('#animCoracao.selected').reel({

                images: url + "un01_a01_p01_#.jpg",
                });

                //slider
                $slider = $(".rg-slider").slider({
                  value: 1,
                  min: 1,
                  max: 60,
                  step: 1,
                  disabled: false,
                  slide: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#animCoracao.selected").trigger("reach", [ui.value, 10]);
                  }
                });
```

As the slider slides it should rotate the reel js object. But the object doesn't rotate when I slide the slider.

It seems that when on the book of moodle, the slider can´t trigger the "reach" method of the reel js element.

It doen't show any javascript error on console.

Comment: probably there is more than one issue, but... one of them could be that `images` seems to be expecting an array of images/urls and you seem to be passing an string (which curiously, the library will treat as an array, eg ['h', 't', 't', 'p'...])